# SSIS package to loop through databases to find a table and delete older rows

Tags: sql, database, ssis

I need help in creating a package that iterates through databases in a given server, looks for a table name that contains the word 'EventLog' and delete all rows older than a year. The deletion should be in batch of 50000.

I was able to read the database names using Execute SQL task, stored the full result set in a object type variable and used for each loop container to read the results from the variable and need help from there

Comment: And have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: You should begin your SSIS career by building this in T-SQL. However if you don't want to do that, then the next step is to put a SQL task inside your for each loop and use expressions to build the statement dynamically. Will the row age always be indicated by the same column? If not, how will you determine it? This link will help you to dynamically set the SQL Tasks contents: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1228615/ssis-expression-in-execute-sql-task

Comment: Yes, there is a column in every table that shows the date( need to delete rows that has date older than a year )and the name of the column is same across databases

Comment: Well then you should have some idea of a sample `DELETE` statement required to be run in each database right? Only the database and table name will change. You build this string dynamically in a SSIS variable and us an expression to stuff this into the execute SQL Task. BTW this can all be achieved with a T-SQL statement (no SSIS at all).

Comment: Could you please elaborate, having trouble understanding

Comment: First drop an execute SQL statement inside your for each container with a hard coded SQL statement. Once you have that working you need to use an expression to alter that statement based on the loop. Take a look at this guide. The section after "Adding the connection Manager" has some information about setting up an expression based off what comes out of your for loop container. Have a try at this and post any specific questions. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Comment: Thank you that's helpful

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple tables that may contain the word 'EventLog' in a single database, you need to add an additional for each (for each table) inside the parent 'for each' container. Build a dynamic delete statement inside this for each container using the variables from the parent and current container.

Your package should look very similar to this:

**Control Flow**
[image]

**Package Variables**
[image]
*add your date filter to the 'delete_log_records_sql' variable*

**Get DB Names - Execute SQL Task**
[image]

**Get DB Names - Assign Results to Object Var**
[image]

**Foreach DB - DB Name Object Var Mapping**
[image]

**Foreach DB - DB Name Collection Var Mapping**
[image]

**Get Table Names - Execute SQL Task**
[image]

**Get Table Names - Assign Results to Object Var**
[image]

**Foreach Table - Table Name Object Var Mapping**
[image]

**Foreach Table - Table Name Collection Var Mapping**
[image]

**Delete Log Records - Execute SQL Task**
[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much everyone , that's very helpful